# How to create a private folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Let say I have folderA and folderB. Any content created on folderA should be reflected on folderB but not in reverse way.

Is there any concept in Linux to achieve this?

Comment: [overlayfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt); `mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/dir/A,upperdir=/dir/B,workdir=/dir/C overlay /dir/B`; if you create a file in `/dir/A` it will also appear in `/dir/B`, but a file created in `/dir/B` will not appear in `/dir/A`.

Comment: Tnx @mosvy , will check that.